# Session Handling in Spring MVC 3.0

Tags: session, spring-mvc

I am using `session.setAttribute` to store user object after login. In next controller, I have  `@SessionAttribute` for the same user and `@ModelAttribute` for same object to be used in the method mapped to a `RequestMapping`. After login if I click any link in the user home page it give

> HttpSessionRequiredException: Session attribute '' required - not found in session

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I went through many article and question in this site as well but could find any solution. The user object which I am storing in session stores user's account details which are required in all the controller to get different information from DB. I using `SessionAttribute` is wrong should I use `HttpSession` instead in all the controller and get the object from session manually or there is a proper way to handle in spring 3.0. Please note that this user object is not backing any form just login, but contains many other details.

As help would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my (non-perfect) use of session data:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("sharedData")
public class RegistrationFormController {

    @Autowired
    private SharedData sharedData; // bean with scope="session"

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/registrationForm"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView newForm() {
        final ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("registrationForm");

        modelAndView.addObject("registrationForm", new RegistrationForm());
        // I want to render some data from this object in JSP:
        modelAndView.addObject("sharedData", sharedData);

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = {"/registrationForm"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String onRegistrationFormSubmitted(HttpServletRequest request,
                @ModelAttribute("registrationForm") RegistrationForm registrationForm, BindingResult result) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "registrationForm";
        }

        // Perform business logic, e.g. persist registration data

        return "formSubmitted";
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi dma_k I guess this will not be helpful in my case as I have user details to be stored in session. And in you example ur storing sharedData which I cannot do as user details cannot be shared.

Comment: @Amit: How do you create your initial user details? E.g. how does the factory method `UserDetials createUserDetails(...) {}` signature look like?